# Beautiful Soup Web scraper creates individual JSON files from individual URLs but JSON files all return last element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

This scraper class is supposed to loop through the CATEGORIES array and then loop through the JSON_FILES concurrently and create individual JSON files. I am trying to use a stack and just append the data to the stack and then pop it off the top so that my stack array only has the current data from the most recent **scrape**. The issue is that each JSON file gets created but it overwrites all of them each time and in the end, they all produce the last element.

How do I make it so the JSON files only save the data that share the same index as the CATEGORIES array?

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Scraper:
    def scrape_category():
        try:
            stack = []
            for url in CATEGORIES:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(BASE_URL + url).text, "lxml")
                stack.append(Scraper.extract_product_info(soup))
                Scraper.create_json_file(stack.pop())
        except ConnectionError:
            print("Couldn't connect to ebay.com! Please try again.")
            exit(1)

    def extract_product_info(soup):
        title = soup.find_all("h3", class_="s-item__title")
        bid = soup.find_all("span", class_="s-item__price")
        link = soup.find_all("a", class_="s-item__link", href=True)
        bid_time = soup.find_all("span", class_="s-item__time-left")
        bid_count = soup.find_all("span", class_="s-item__bids s-item__bidCount")

        data = []

        for title, bid, link, bid_time, bid_count in zip(
            title, bid, link, bid_time, bid_count
        ):
            data.append(
                {
                    "Title": title.getText(),
                    "Bid": bid.getText(),
                    "Link": link["href"],
                    "Bid_Time": bid_time.getText(),
                    "Bid_Count": bid_count.getText(),
                }
            )
        return data

    def create_json_file(data):
        for file in JSON_FILES:
            json_file = open(file, "w")
            json.dump(data, json_file, indent=2)
            json_file.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    BASE_URL = "https://www.ebay.com/b/"

    CATEGORIES = [
        "Apple-Cell-Phones-Smartphones/9355/bn_319682?LH_Auction=1&rt=nc",
        "Samsung-Cell-Phones-and-Smartphones/9355/bn_352130?LH_Auction=1&rt=nc",
        "Google-Cell-Phones-Smartphones/9355/bn_3904160?LH_Auction=1&rt=nc",
        "LG-Cell-Phones-and-Smartphones/9355/bn_353985?LH_Auction=1&rt=nc",
    ]

    JSON_FILES = ["apple.json", "samsung.json", "google.json", "lg.json"]

    Scraper.scrape_category()
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked through it, and decided to get rid of the `create_json_file` function entirely, and instead made the `scrape_category` function look like this:

```
 def scrape_category():
    try:
        for url, filename in zip(CATEGORIES, JSON_FILES):
            soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(BASE_URL + url).text, "lxml")
            data = Scraper.extract_product_info(soup)
            with open(filename, "w") as json_file:
                json.dump(data, json_file, indent=2)
        print("Files created successfully!")

    except ConnectionError:
        print("Couldn't connect to ebay.com! Please try again.")
        exit(1)
```